# CSV files to ZIP - PHP code

Tags: php

I want to download multiple CSV files via PHP, and I know that's not possible because you can't make more than 1 Request per time.

Had an ideea to create multiple CSV files and save them into a ZIP file, and download that. Is it possible? If yes, can you give me a help, with 2 CSV files stored into 1 ZIP file and download it? THank you.

My code until now:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$filenameZIP = "./fileZIP.zip";

if ($zip->open($filenameZIP, \ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filenameZIP>\n");
}

$filenameCSV = 'file1';
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filenameCSV . '";');

$f = fopen('php://output', 'a+');

$array    = array();
$array[0] = array(
   'first11',
   'first12',
);
$array[1] = array(
   'first21',
   'first22',
);

foreach ($array as $line) {
   fputcsv($f, $line, ';');
}

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fileZIP.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($zip->filename);

$zip->close();
```

Comment: Are you downloading files from a different site, or offering files for download from your own site? I'm not even clear on that much from your question...

Comment: what's *not* happening here? you didn't say. Are you seeing `exit("cannot open <$filenameZIP>\n");` ?

Comment: I want to save multiple CSV Files into a ZIP File, and download that ZIP File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I've saved CSV Files on the server, added them to ZIP with ZipArchive::addFile(), and then removed CSV Files from the server.